# How to average sub arrays in Numpy using broadcasting?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, array-broadcasting

If there is a numpy array that is a list of 2d arrays, is there more efficient way than calling the mean function twice?

```
z = np.array([[[0, 0, 0],
               [10, 10, 10]],
              [[0, 0, 0],
               [5, 5, 5]],
              [[0, 0, 0],
               [2, 2, 2]]])
print(z.mean(axis=2).mean(axis=1))
>[ 5.   2.5  1. ]
```

Comment: Use tuple of axes : `z.mean(axis=(1,2))`.

Comment: perfect.  that works exactly as I need.  thank you!